# can't call function setTemplate in controller admin magento2?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

in my Controller i call

```
 public function execute()
    {   

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        echo $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('productquestion_edit_tab_answerquestion')->setTemplate('Mageaddons_Productquestion::answers/edit.phtml'); die('xxx');
        ..}
```

Get Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on boolean

Answer (score 0):

This means that you do not have a block in the layout with name 'productquestion_edit_tab_answerquestion'.

Also _view property is deprecated, please use

```
 /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
 $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
 $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock(...)
```

Comment: For exmaple `$resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('checkout.cart.totals');`. setTemplate() is not required